# How to uncheck all below checkboxes when one checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxfor

I have a dynamic set of checkboxes which are already mark. When I click one out of it then all the below checkboxes should be unchecked and if re mark again all the above checkbox mark again. Is there anyone who can help me on this please?

Thank you.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.transportDate.Count(); i++)
{
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.transportDate[i].selection)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.transportDate[i].Date)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
}
```

[image: Overview of question]

Comment: you will need to write some javascript or jquery code to handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on the Client side using `javascript`. See example.

```js
$('#tbl [type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  var $this = this; //save clicked chk
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) //nothing to do
    return;
  var uncheck = false;
  $(this).parents('table') //get container
    .find('[type=checkbox]') //get siblings
    .each(function() { //iterate
      if (this === $this) //found
        uncheck = true;
      if (uncheck)
        this.checked = false; //clear checkbox
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>other</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How to perform reverse logic for example if user uncheck a checkbox and mark a checkbox below after two unchecked checkbox, so that we also mark all checkbox to checked till top. @Alex

Comment: In `.each` function set `this.checked=true` and at `if(this===$this)` `return false` to break from the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your checkboxes, you need to store them in an array and use the same onClick function for them all with a parameter being the index of the Chekbox in the array.

When the user clicks on it, you just need to loop through the array and change the status as needed.

pseudo-code sample:

```
let _checkboxesArray = [];
function createDynamicCheckboxes() {
  _checkboxesArray = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < Model.transportDate.Count(); i ++) {
    _checkboxesArray[i] = 'cb' + i;
    // create your checkbox and assign it the id we just stored.
    dCheckbox.id = _checkboxesArray[i];
    let li = i;
    dCheckbox.onClick = (function(index) {
      for (let j = 0; j < Model.transportDate.Count(); j ++) {
        document.getElementById(_checkboxesArray[j]).checked = j < index;
      }
    }(li));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with javascript if the checkbox is checked.

So, if the checkbox is checked, uncheck the others:

`document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;`
`document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = false;`